# Collapsing or hiding code in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse

I have a main method with a hundreed lines of code.

I want to collapse some of it so that I can work on other parts, but I don't want to wrap it in a method.

Is there any way I can just highlight some code and collapse it?

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting your screen. That way no folding is required and you would be able to look at two parts of the same class.

```
    Ctrl + Shift + '-' to split horizontally,
    Ctrl + Shift + - '[' to split vertically.
```